# How do you rescale images with exact dimensions in Adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a rectangle art-board. I am trying to place 3 identical vector graphics in different colors onto the board. I want them to be scaled, spaced apart evenly. I can't seem to find the rescale function where I can enter exact dimensions that I want. I know you can drag to scale via toolbar icon but this doesn't fit my needs.

I am using latest version of Adobe illustrator CC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enter the size you want in the **Control Bar**

[image]

Or the **Transform Panel**

[image]

If you really want to scale... just double-click the **Scale Tool** or choose `Object > Transform > Scale...` from the menu

[image]

You may also find the **Distribute Spacing** buttons on the **Align Panel** helpful in getting the three objects evenly spaced.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I don't see the Control Bar option. I prefer this over the Transform Panel.

Comment: The control bar option will only appear if your monitor is large enough to show it. Otherwise you get a link to the Transform Panel.

Comment: So from this answer I've learned you literally can't rescale images to an exact size. Illustrator is software for idiots.

Comment: The nature of "scale" is relative. So yes, only by percentages. It is possible to *resize* objects to specific dimensions, but that's not "scaling" as Adobe sees it. Illustrator is **not**, and has never been marketed as, a CAD application. If you need precise scaling, you need CAD.